# Notify UITable from an other Thread

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, data-binding

I've got a simple UITable implementation and an array which is called fruits. Taken out of [this](https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/) example. The only difference is that I am using a UIViewController for the UITable insted of a UITableViewController, but this should be irrelevant for now.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var fruits : [String] = Array() 
    let thread : GetDataForFruitsArrayThread

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fruits.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = fruits[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    }
```

Now I have got a viewDidLoad function in this class also. In the function I am calling a thread which is getting the array as a parameter. The thread is filling up the array with new values asynchronously. Means I don't know if there will be any values or when do the value appear and are set into the array. So you can imagine what I want to ask on this point: How do I signal the UITableView that I have changed the content of the array once the view has loaded the array into the UITable. In c# there is the NotifyAll() function which notfies all the Listener to an attribute. Is there an easy and performant way to do this in swift, optionally without importing any non-included libraries?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.thread = GetDataForFruitsArrayThread(array: &fruits)
    self.thread.StartAsynchronously() 

}
```

EDIT - adding GetDataForFruitsArrayThread

```
 class GetDataForFruitsArrayThread : MyThread {

 var array : [String]

 init(array: inout [String] ) {
   self.array = array
 }


 override func main() {

      // init socket

 while(true){

      _ = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &rcvaddr){
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1){
      recvfrom(m_socket, &pData, bufferlength, 0, UnsafeMutablePointer($0), 
               &socketAddressLength)
            }
        }

        var fruit = String(cString:inet_ntoa(rcvaddr.sin_addr), encoding: .ascii)
        self.array.append(fruit)

   }
 }
}
```

**EDIT - 21.11.2017:**

Following Sandeep Bhandari's answer I changed the following code in the ViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView1: UITableView!

var fruits : [String] = Array() {
        didSet {
            self.tableView1.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

PROBLEM: I am setting a breakpoint at array.append(fruit) in the GetDataForFruitsArrayThread-class. After that there is a breakpoint in the didSet method. But this breakpoint does not get called after the append()-call! NOTE: The parameter on the init function of the GetDataForFruitsArrayThread-class is an in-out parameter!

UPDATE: I found out that if I do the array.append(fruit)-call on the GetDataForFruitsArrayThread.array in the GetDataForFruitsArrayThread-thread, the Fruits-array in ViewController-class does not get changed, therefore didSet did not get called. How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: Add a Closure parameter to your method, a callback to get notified when your network function ends

Comment: The function does not end at all, it is an endless thread which tries to receive packets from the network while the app is running. Do you mean that I should pass a handle as parameter which gets called everytime an element is appended? If yes, then what should happen in the ViewController if the handler is triggered? A UITable reload somehow, how could this work?

Comment: its the same approach add a closure and execute this closure with your array of objects as parameter, every time you need, and when this closure is called you must update your viewController array of objects and update your UITableView according

Comment: Do you have some examples/samples on this closure? I don't exactly understand what it should do

Comment: I think that maybe with your `viewController` acting as delegate of your `GetDataForFruitsArrayThread` your viewController can be notified, you must also declare your thread variable in your class scope, I am not 100% sure but maybe is deallocated after viewDidLoad ends, this is another way to do this

Comment: changed the scope problem for the future. How can I set the `viewController` as delegate ?

Comment: post your `GetDataForFruitsArrayThread` class implementation to try with an answer for you

Comment: posted it, a little bit minimalistic, but the main function are there.

Comment: the answer provided by Sandeep must solve your issue, let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you said you are running a endless process to keep updating your array and you want the UI update once the array changes you can use the below solution.

```
var fruits : [String] = Array() {
        didSet {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

What am I doing ? Simple added a setter to array and whenever value changes I reload the tableView.

**EDIT:**

The above solution will work only if you modify the inout fruits array you pass to `GetDataForFruitsArrayThread`

```
self.thread = GetDataForFruitsArrayThread(array: &fruits)
```

So don't create  one more array property in `GetDataForFruitsArrayThread` rather directly modify the array passed to GetDataForFruitsArrayThread.

Comment: By the edit you mean to not do this in the constructor of `GetDataForFruitsArrayThread`: self.array = fruits. Right? But then how can I get access on the fruits parameter in the main()-function if I do not safe it to the array variable?

Comment: @david : Nope, thats not what I meant what you are doing is fine:) What I meant is use the same instance of array that has been passed to you and don't create a separate instance of array. I hope u are aware of deep n shallow copy. InOut params are passed by reference. So use the same reference. I wrote that edit when you half posted your question. Looking the variable named array I thought you might be having new instance of array rather than using the one passed to you :)

Comment: self.array = fruits will not create a new instance of array but rather creates a pointer to same array which is fine self.array = [String]() would create a new instance second one will not work with proposed solution. What you are doing now should work fine :)

Comment: @David: Please consider accepting answer if it helped :)

Comment: First of all thank you for the help. I will try as soon as my Xcode updated (may take time) and if it does work (but it sounds about right and exactly what I need) I will accept and upvote your anser of course!! At the moment I'm just asking theoretically, when I have the chance to try I will also send some feedback.

Comment: @david : Sure sir! Happy coding

Comment: Sir, I edited my question, your suggestion does not work yet. Do you have any suggestions?